# How to calculate the disabled text color for controls that look very close to Winforms controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I am using CustomButton and CustomLabel derived from Button and Label. They have extra functionality that I need.

The visual difference is minimal but I don't know how .NET calculates Winforms disabled colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pull the color from System.Drawing.SystemColors.  For a label or text on a disabled control (for example) you want the equiv of COLOR_GRAYTEXT ( from GetSysColor windows API), which is System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText.

See the descriptions of system colors at the [help for GetSysColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724371%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Specifically SystemColors.GrayText